# Does %USERPROFILE%\Desktop work in all language versions?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a `cmd` batch script which writes output to a file in `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\`.

Would that also work in non-English versions of Windows 10?

I don't have a system in another language to check, but I know that Explorer shows it with a different name. Is it only the Explorer display which does a translation, or does the directory actually have a different name in the file system?

Comment: In a German edition of Windows Server 2016, the absolute path is `C:\Benutzer\username\Desktop`, but if you try to copy it out, it copies as `C:\Users\username\Desktop`. `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\` also takes me to the correct location.

Comment: Microsoft offers developers free VMs. You should test this edge condition if you are worried

Comment: Yes, this should always work.  Good or bad.. some of the things in windows (and other OSs) are tied to English.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't granted in English or any language since the desktop can also be somewhere in Onedrive. To be sure you have to check in:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

and look for the "Desktop" data

or by using powershell:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
```

Comment: This method most definitely would require the localized version of the variable. The variable names might be identical for a vast majority of languages but it’s not guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: The variables names itself are the same for all languages as far as I know.